# SSMS 18.4 overwrites passwords has same user name but different server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When you want to login different servers using "Object Explorer" tool, SQL Server Management Studio 18 overrides passwords with same username.

For example, login a server with "remember password" option like following

`Server: ASERVER
Login: auser
Password: apassword`

And then login to another server (again "remember password") like following (same user name different password)

`Server: ANOTHERSERVER
Login: auser
Password: anotherpassword`

Unfortunately SSMS overrides the first username/password. That is, if you try to reconnect `ASERVER` again SSMS gives username/password error. This is so annoying. Any help?

**EDIT:** The problem is actually very simple. Open a connection SERVER1 and then SERVER2 using the Object Explorer. If user name has same, SERVER1 password is gone.

**EDIT 2:** SSMS's password management switched to Windows Credential Manager with version 18: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#download-ssms-180

Comment: I did not follow what you're saying here at all. SSMS stores credentials per login, which is unique to an Instance, not login name. If you have the same login name for 2 different servers you'll need to tell it what the password is for both, not one.

Comment: Use registered servers to store credentials for different instances. The remember password in the login dialog doesn't consider the context of the instance you're connecting to.

Comment: @Larnu But this was not the case with SSMS v17. Please read my edit.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks. this hadn't come to my mind. good workaround.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that hasn't changed since at least SSMS 2008

Comment: Microsoft moved the SSMS's password management into Windows Credential Manager with version 18.

Comment: @iBener I'm having exact same problem. Did you find a fix yet?

Comment: @ÖmerCinbat a workaround, registered servers.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you remove that server from the SSMS Server History, it'll still not save the fully qualified settings in Windows Credentials. It'll save an entry with the UserName/Password instead of the ServerName/UserName/Password.

**TL;DR**

1. Open Registered Servers (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and delete all the severs in the Local Server Groups (not sure if critical but I did).
2. Open the **File** menu, **Connect to Server** selection. In the dialog,
   dropdown the Server name and use the arrow keys to highlight the
   affected server name and hit the Delete key to remove it from the
   SSMS history.  **This step is critical.**
3. Now that the entry is out of the SSMS History, use that same dialog to connect to the server making sure to click **[X] Remember password**.

Voila! If you look in Windows Credentials you'll see the entry with the fully qualified ServerName:UserName.

**More Detail...**

The Windows Credentials are visible at:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager

If you have connections saved in the 'Local Server Groups' under "Registered Servers", they won't be migrated automatically to Windows Credentials correctly.

It will create a Windows Credential record for that connection's username but without the server names scope.  This seems to be the real problem.

Here's the Windows Credential for my common logon. Note the missing ServerName between the two colons:

```
Microsoft:SSMS:18::MySampleUserName
```

It should've been:

```
Microsoft:SSMS:18:MyServerName.Domain.com:MySampleUserName
```

If you have the same username for 2 or more servers, this one Windows Credential record password will be overwritten each time you logon.

I tried deleting this entry from the Windows Credentials but that wasn't sufficient to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear when the problem occurs. According to my tests, if you have 2 different connections to same server in object explorer and you create new query window from object explorer, the connections are applied correctly.
Maybe you are talking about recent connection in the "New Query" command?
If you have to deal with multiple connections you can use at least built-in "Registered Servers" functionality.

Or, you can use SSMSBoost add-in (that I develop) to have seamless "preferred connections" and "recent connections" management.

Here is a video about the feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Up6EQux9LM

Description: https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-preferred-connections